# Maven: Only execute plugin when a command line flag is present

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-2, command-line-arguments, maven-antrun-plugin

I want Maven to only run a certain plugin when there is a flag on the command line when I call the `mvn` command.

for example:

Let's say I have a plugin called `maven-foo-plugin`. I only want maven to run this plugin when the flag `--foo` is present when I call the maven command.

So, instead of saying...

```
mvn install
```

...I would say...

```
mvn install --foo
```

The first one should NOT use/call the plugin `maven-foo-plugin`, but the second one should. By default, I don't want this plugin to run, but if and only if, the `--foo` is present. Is there another parameter that I add to this `maven-foo-plugin` to make it do this?

The plugin I'm using is the `maven-antrun-plugin` that has the task that unzips a file. Of course, sometimes this file is present and sometimes not. Sometimes, it's not present and I don't need it. So, I need a way (Preferably through command line unless someone has a better idea) to turn on/off this plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Gab has mentioned, using Maven profiles is the way to go. Create a profile and configure your plugin in the profile. Then in the profile's `activation` section, reference the environment variable, with or without a value:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>debug</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The above example would activate the profile if you define the `debug` variable when calling Maven:

```
mvn install -Ddebug
```

Please note that you have to prefix environment variables with `-D` in order to pass them to the JVM running Maven.

More details can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Within that profile, are you allowed to run two plugins? one right after another?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many plugins as you like in the profile. Each profile has a `build/plugins` section, where you can list plugins just like you're doing in your main build.

Comment: If I do have two plugin within one profile, how do I say for which one to run first?

Comment: Each plugin execution is bound to a phase, some plugins are bound to a phase by default, e.g. the jar plugin, others not. You can use the phase tag to specify when a plugin is executed. See here for more details on phases: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to trigger conditional action in maven is to use profile.
You can so configure a specific profile including the plugin activation, you will then trigger  the execution using

`mvn targetPhase -P myprofile`

(you can also specify a specific property value to activate the profile)

see [Maven: Using a Plugin Based On Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063979/maven-using-a-plugin-based-on-profile)