# Generate property file as per environment by passing multiple environment

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, pom.xml

I have one situation where I need to create multiple configuration property file by passing environment.

i.e : I have environment like dev, prod, qa, int, but I want to create jar only for int and dev in one go

My First question is: "Is there any way in  maven where we can pass multiple environment value" ?

If this is possible how can I setup my pom.xml to accept the multiple env value ?

Comment: how did you manage your environments ? profiles ?

Comment: You really don't want to be doing this. You should have one jar file that is promoted through environments without change, otherwise you could get something wrong after qa testing and put the wrong thing in production. Best practice is to test the artifacts in dev, test the same artifact in int, if it passes that then test it in qa, then in pre-prod, then push it to prod -- same artifact. Properties, like db connection strings and credentials, should be kept in external files or in ldap.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean with "pass multiple environment value".

If you want to activate a set of properties depending on the execution environment you could use maven profiles.

Here is an example for two profiles, which you can add to a pom.xml.

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <value1>a</value1>
            <value2>b</value2>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <value1>x</value1>
            <value2>y</value2>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You could then for example activate profile "prod" by calling maven with the paramter "-Pprod".

Comment: As I read the question, the OP wants to be able to create both files with one command.  Profiles won't work for this.

Comment: Profiles may still be useful, as you could configure different execution blocks for the relevant plugins and then activate multiple profiles at once. But I guess we would need to know more about his environment.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you can't trigger 2 different packaging with per-profile filtered resources in one build.

If you want to activate 2 profile at once you can specify them both using -P or trigger the activation according to the same property (see [Maven: Only execute plugin when a command line flag is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524500/maven-only-execute-plugin-when-a-command-line-flag-is-present/15524609#15524609))

If I correctly understand your question, i'd suggest to delegate the build of the integration artifact to a continuous integration server which will trigger the appropriate resource filtering using a dedicated profile and to set the dev profile as default one for the daily developers builds.