# Can Maven run non-build tasks?

Tags: java, ant, maven-3

I moved from Ant to Maven and I miss one thing: the ability to execute an arbitrary task. I wanted to get rid of Ant's `build.xml` but I still need it just for this.

Occasionally I need to run some stats for XML processing and PDF processing. **They are not part of the build** but I need to automate them anyway. In Ant I used to just compile and run a java class in the code to using the `java` Ant task, e.g.:

```
<target name="gen-stats">
  <java classname="com.utl.StatsGen" classpath="build" />
</target>

<target name="compute-complexity">
  <java classname="com.utl.PDFComplexity" classpath="lib/pdf-cpx.jar" />
</target>
```

Trying to wrap my brain around it. Maybe Maven wasn't designed to do help with *any automation*, but only addresses "build oriented" tasks. Is it?

Comment: You could utilize the maven-antrun-plugin as described here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html

Comment: @DrHopfen I was hoping to get rid of the build.xml. What's the "Maven way" of doing this?

Comment: You don't need a separate build.xml to use the maven-antrun-plugin. You add the plugin to your project and nest Ant targets directly inside the configuration block. If you want to avoid Ant altogether, the truly Maven way would be to create a Maven plugin of your own that does specifically what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, *Maven* define **Phases**, **Goals**, **Plugins** and **Lifecycles**.

**Phase**: A stage during a defined build *Lifecycle*.
Each *Phase* is a **sequence of goals**.

**Goal**: A *Goal* is responsible for a specific **task**.

**Plugin**: A *Plugin* is a **group of *Goals*** (*Goals* aren't necessarily all bound to the same *phase*).

**Lifecycle**: A *Lifecycle* is a **sequence of *Phases***.

Having said that, there is a default set of Maven's **Lifecycles**.

- default (main lifecycle responsible for handle project deployment -build and deploy your project-)
- clean (lifecycle responsible for handle project cleaning)
- site (lifecycle reponsible for create project's site documentation)

**Default Lifecycle phases**

```
<phases>
  <phase>validate</phase>
  <phase>initialize</phase>
  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
  <phase>process-sources</phase>
  <phase>generate-resources</phase>
  <phase>process-resources</phase>
  <phase>compile</phase>
  <phase>process-classes</phase>
  <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
  <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
  <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
  <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
  <phase>test-compile</phase>
  <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
  <phase>test</phase>
  <phase>prepare-package</phase>
  <phase>package</phase>
  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
  <phase>integration-test</phase>
  <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
  <phase>verify</phase>
  <phase>install</phase>
  <phase>deploy</phase>
</phases>
```

**Clean Lifecycle phases**

```
<phases>
  <phase>pre-clean</phase>
  <phase>clean</phase>
  <phase>post-clean</phase>
</phases>
<default-phases>
  <clean>
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean
  </clean>
</default-phases>
```

**Site Lifecycle phases**

```
<phases>
  <phase>pre-site</phase>
  <phase>site</phase>
  <phase>post-site</phase>
  <phase>site-deploy</phase>
</phases>
<default-phases>
  <site>
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site
  </site>
  <site-deploy>
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:deploy
  </site-deploy>
</default-phases>
```

See you that in *default* lifecycle there is not **default-phases** defined. It's because default phases to be executed in this lifecycle are specific defined for each packaging (ear, jar, war, rar, pom, etc). See [default lifecycle bindings](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html).

So, if you run 'mvn PHASE' eg. 'mvn install' you will execute default lifecycle *INSTALL* phase and all the preceding phases as well (this will execute all phases except those after the one defined 'install','deploy' will not be executed).

When you run 'mvn PLUGIN:GOAL' executes the defined plugin goal eg. 'mvn compiler:compile'. It will run all phases up to the defined phase (and all goals in those phases) including your defined goal.

---

There are a set of plugins that you can use to execute a OS command or a java process. Also there is a plugin to run **Ant tasks** that can be useful.

**Mojo Exec plugin**
[mojo exec plugin reference](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html)

Eg. Execution using command line:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"] ...
```

Eg. Execution using a POM configuration:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>argument1</argument>
            ...
          </arguments>
          <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <key>myproperty</key>
              <value>myvalue</value>
            </systemProperty>
            ...
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

**Maven Antrun plugin**
[antrun plugin reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/plugin-info.html)

Eg. POM configuration:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.8</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The maven-antrun-plugin has only one goal, run.

Eg. command line execution:

```
mvn antrun:run
```

More about usage and how to define your Ant targets in pom.xml:
[usage](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html)

**Antrun usage example**

1 - Add plugin definition like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>my-gen-stats-task</id>
            <phase>pre-site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                        <target name="gen-stats"/>
                    </ant>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

2 - Execute your defined maven phase:

```
mvn pre-site
```

---

You can play with SITE lifecycle... Try this example and see how if you run 'mvn pre-site' only your ant tasks defined in 'pre-site' phase are executed. Try running 'mvn site' and see how 'pre-site' and 'site' tasks are executed:

Eg.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-pre-site</id>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>PRE-SITE PHASE!!!</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-site</id>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>SITE PHASE!!!</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-post-site</id>
                        <phase>post-site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>POST-SITE PHASE!!!</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-site-deploy</id>
                        <phase>site-deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>SITE DEPLOY PHASE!!!</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It seems the "Mojo Exec plugin" could the best fit for me since I have around 15 different tasks to automate; by changing the command line parameters I will be able to choose which task to run. I don't think creating 15 lifecycles, one per task, is a good idea (it may be overkill). Also I don't think reusing an existing lifecycle ("site") is a good fit for automating 15 tasks either.

Comment: Yes, exec plugin is a simple solution! Also, You can use maven profiles to isolate executions with activations too (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525624/2493852). Or you can implement your own maven plugin or build your own custom lifecycle but this is a little more tricky.